# JBoss 7 missing jboss.naming.context.java - can't run EAR

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I'm trying to run an ear on jboss 7 and everytime I run the ear I get this error:

> "Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" =>
>   ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"PROJECTNAME.jar#PROJECTNAMEPU\" missing [
>   jboss.naming.context.java.PROJECTNAME ]"]

Also before this error I get this feedback for every session/entity bean;

> INFO
>   [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor]
>   (MSC service thread 1-8) JNDI bindings for session bean named
>   SESSIONBEAN in deployment unit subdeployment "PROJECTNAME.war" of
>   deployment "PROJECTNAME.ear" are as follows:

I tried looking it up and idk what I'm missing, any suggestions or help??

**UPDATE:**
In my standalone.xml for jboss

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PROJECTNAME" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="PROJECTNAME" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER:PORT:support</connection-url>
    <driver>ojdbc14.jar</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>USERNAME</user-name>
        <password>PASS</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PROJECTNAME" pool-name="PROJECTNAME">
   <driver>ojdbc14.jar</driver>
   <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER</xa-datasource-property>
   <xa-pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
   </xa-pool>
   <security>
        <user-name>USERNAME</user-name>
        <password>PASS</password>
   </security>
</xa-datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc14">
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

My persitence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PROJECTNAMEPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PROJECTNAME</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your EAR requires some JNDI bindings to be configured in JBoss, likely DataSources for use by JPA.  Java EE applications can have dependencies on services provided by the container and those are usually looked up using the naming service (JNDI).

Check the deploy/install instructions that come with the EAR you're trying to deploy, or refer back to whoever provides the application.  Unfortunately it's not possible to provide much more help without much more info.

Comment: added info about my standalone.xml for jboss, would persistence.xml info help too? or what info would you need?